# Install package in running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apt

i've been using a docker container to build the chromium browser (building for Android on Debian 10). I've already created a Dockerfile that contains most of the packages I need.

Now, after building and running the container, I followed the [instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md), which asked me to execute an install script (./build/install-build-deps-android.sh). In this script multiple apt install commands are executed.

My question now is, is there a way to install these packages without rebuilding the container? Downloading and building it took rather long, plus rebuilding a container each time a new package is required seems kind of suboptimal. The error I get when executing the install script is:

```
./build/install-build-deps-android.sh: line 21: lsb_release: command not found
```

(I guess there will be multiple missing packages). And using apt will give:

```
root@677e294147dd:/android-build/chromium/src# apt install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nginx
```

(nginx just as an example install).

I'm thankfull for any hints, as I could only find guides that use the Dockerfile to install packages.

Comment: You may find the `exec` command helpful https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description, it allows you to run a command in already running container.

Comment: Remember that any changes you make in a running container will be lost as soon as the container exits, and you need to delete and recreate containers for some pretty routine Docker-level settings changes.  I'd consider changing the Dockerfile (and committing it to source control) better practice.

Answer (score 28):

*You can use docker commit:*

1. Start your container `sudo docker run IMAGE_NAME`
2. Access your container using bash: `sudo docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`
3. Install whatever you need inside the container
4. Exit container's bash
5. Commit your changes: `sudo docker commit CONTAINER_ID NEW_IMAGE_NAME`

If you run now `docker images`, you will see `NEW_IMAGE_NAME` listed under your local images.

Next time, when starting the docker container, use the new docker image  you just created:
`sudo docker run **NEW_IMAGE_NAME**` - this one will include your additional installations.

Answer based on the following tutorial: [How to commit changes to docker image](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-commit-changes-to-a-docker-image/)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for @adnanmuttaleb and @David Maze (unfortunately, they only replied, so I cannot accept their answers).

What I did was to edit the Dockerfile for any later updates (which already happened), and use the exec command to install the needed dependencies from outside the container. Also remember to

```
apt update
```

otherwise you cannot find anything...

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you.

This can be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed: `apt update`. None of the other answers mentioned that. You should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

A slight variation of the steps suggested by [Arye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3201682/arye) that worked better for me:

1. Create container from image and access in interactive mode: `docker run -it IMAGE_NAME bin/bash`
2. Modify container as desired
3. Leave container: `exit`
4. List launched containers: `docker ps -a` and copy the ID of the container just modified
5. Save to a new image: `docker commit CONTAINER_ID NEW_IMAGE_NAME`

If you haven't followed the [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)
, you might have to prefix Docker commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Fewer steps than from arye and the hint to use "docker ps -a" to get the container id was what I was missing. Thanks.